# Let $a_n = (n + \frac {1}{n}) $,$ n \in N$ ,then the sum of the series $\sum(-1)^{n+1} \frac{a_{n+1}}{n!}$ is

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n = (n + \frac {1}{n}) $,$ n \in N$ ,then the sum of the series  $\sum(-1)^{n+1} \frac{a_{n+1}}{n!}$  is

which is  the correct option?

1) $e^{-1}-1$

2) $e^{-1}$

3) $1- e^{-1}$

4)$ 1+e^{-1}$

By stirling formula  $n! =e^n n^{-n}$

i got the answer option 2

Comment: `by stirling formula` That's an approximation, only, and a pretty loose approximation at small $n$ for that matter. You cannot use that to find the (exact) sum of the series.

Comment: This Stirling formula, when $n=1$, implies that $e=1$.

Comment: Also, what made you choose option 2 over option 1?

Comment: oh sorry @ArnaudMortier..i have  edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
\begin{equation*}
e^{-1}\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=1-1+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\dots
\end{equation*}

Since
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\quad (n\in\mathbb{N})
\end{equation*}it follows that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}&=1-1+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\dots=e^{-1}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}&=1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+\dots=1-e^{-1}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}&=\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\dots=e^{-1}.
\end{align*}Consequently, we conclude that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}}{n!}=1+e^{-1}.
\end{equation}

Therefore, I think the answer should be option 4.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are alternating and decreasing (verify this!), so the sum is sandwiched between any two successive partial sums.  The terms (starting from $n=1$?) are
$$
\frac{2+1/2}{1!}-\frac{3+1/3}{2!}+\frac{4+1/4}{3!}-\ldots=\frac{5}{2}-\frac{5}{3}+\frac{17}{24}-\ldots.
$$
The partial sums are
$$
\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{6},\frac{37}{24},\ldots;
$$
from the first two alone you can tell that only option $4$ is possible.